# run by default on startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working with a test project and I'm trying to wrap my head around migrations.

I've created a database with the name: `AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth` 
Then in my startup I add a configuration to the Db and point to the Migrations Assembly:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
          b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth")));
```

When I start my test project and I Get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.'

I'm under then Impression that I've provided the MigrationsAssembly so migrations can be run when the project starts.

I'm aware I can update my database through the command line using the Update-Database command.

But why do I have to provide an assembly for migrations in the start up if they're not run by the application by default.  How can I run migrations by default on startup?

Comment: Your test project is calling your startup?

Comment: Yeah, the test project is calling the startup, and it runs but when I attempt to hit the DB I get that error because migrations don't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting MigrationsAssembly just tells the context where to find the migrations assembly, you still need to explicity run it (many times you don't want to run migrations every time you start the application). You need to call

```
myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

To execute the migrations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime